# html editor cursor focus problem

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with textbox and an html editor. When the page is loaded the cursor is focussing on the html editor. instead i want to focus the cursor on the textbox how can i do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer by setting the Autofocus property to false of the html editor

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here.  You can use JavaScript:

```
<body onload="javascript:document.Form1.TextBox1.focus();">
```

or, if you are using a `Form`, then you can do the following:

```
<form id="Form1" defaultfocus="textbox" runat="server"> 
     <asp:textbox id="textbox1" runat="server"/> 
     <asp:textbox id="textbox2" runat="server"/> 
     <asp:button id="button1" text="Button1" runat="server"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: i am sorry to say you Ardman that my controls are in a content place holder

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using mroe Javascript based stuff, may I recommend jQuery? 
http://www.jquery.com/

and use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formID .textboxClass').focus();
});
```